# Distance between two vertices from the ER graph.

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $G$ be an [ER graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model) $G = G(n,p)$ which is constructed by connecting nodes randomly and each edge is included in the graph with probability $p$ independent from every other edge.

For every pair of vertices $(u,v)$, the distance $d(u,v)$ is the length of the shortest path from $u$ to $v$.
Let $q(m) = \Pr[d(u,v) = m]$. What is known about $q(\cdot)$?

Indeed,

- $q(1) = p$ and $q(2) = (1-(1-p^2)^{n-2})(1-p)$
- $q(1)+ q(2) + \cdots + q(n) = 1$

I think there is not a closed form of $q(\cdot)$ perhaps.
Is there an asymptotic formula of $q(\cdot)$?

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by $ER(n, p)$? Is it the same as $G(n, p)$?

Comment: @Paralyzed_by_Time Yes, It is same as $G(n,p)$